# Unable to start NiFi after inconsistent status (Found invalid connectable ID for source)

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache NiFi 1.15.2 deployed using Docker.

Yesterday I was making some modifications to a processing flow in NiFi by copying and deleting some processors, while doing this one of the processors was left with the Success relation of the previous processor "flying" so, an arrow was coming to the processor but I couldn't delete the relation nor the processor it was pointing to.

I was unable to remove this inconsistency from the NiFi dashboard so I tried rebooting to see if I could fix it but now  NiFi won't start showing the following error:

```sh
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1142)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:170)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:82)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:330)
nifi_1 | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found Invalid Connectable ID for Source: 971d7dfc-017e-1000-b899-30e28186fdc5
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addConnections(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1640)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1343)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.updateFlow(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:433)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:283)
nifi_1 | ... 43 common frames omitted
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,241 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=135ms
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,243 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.C._nifi_content_viewer No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,292 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3dde5f38{nifi-content-viewer,/nifi-content-viewer,file:///opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.15.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server-nar-1.15.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.15.2.war}
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,331 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=11ms
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,337 WARN [main] o.e.j.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor Duplicate mapping from / to default
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,341 INFO [main] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler._nifi_docs No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,401 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@79ad1774{nifi-docs,/nifi-docs,file:///opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.15.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server-nar-1.15.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.15.2.war}
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,442 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=15ms
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,509 INFO [main] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler._ No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,517 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@64f3ca6{nifi-error,/,file:///opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.15.2.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-server-nar-1.15.2.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.15.2.war}
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,782 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@d969452{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443}
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,782 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @35388ms
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,782 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
nifi_1 | org.apache.nifi.controller.serialization.FlowSynchronizationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found Invalid Connectable ID for Source: 971d7dfc-017e-1000-b899-30e28186fdc5
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:306)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.synchronize(FlowController.java:1475)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.load(StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.java:89)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:810)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:539)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:67)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1067)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:996)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
nifi_1 | at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1142)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:170)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:82)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:330)
nifi_1 | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found Invalid Connectable ID for Source: 971d7dfc-017e-1000-b899-30e28186fdc5
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addConnections(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1640)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1343)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addNestedProcessGroups(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1352)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.addProcessGroup(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:1341)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.updateFlow(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:433)
nifi_1 | at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowSynchronizer.sync(StandardFlowSynchronizer.java:283)
nifi_1 | ... 43 common frames omitted
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,783 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown started
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,790 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@d969452{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443}
nifi_1 | 2022-03-18 10:27:42,790 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session node0 Stopped scavenging
nifi_nifi_1 exited with code 0
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: try to delete ‘work’ directory .  compose down  and then up may work if you use docker compose

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by uncompressing the `flow.xml.gz` file and removing the ID (`971d7dfc-017e-1000-b899-30e28186fdc5` in your case) raised the error in the file flow.xml. After that, I compress the `flow.xml` file and restart the nifi service. If the error ID appears again, remove these ID again.